# How do I work with Regex having both " and ' in php?

Tags: php, regex, string

My regex is

```
/\?symfony=\w{32}("|')/
```

but php takes regex as a string and I am not able to form that, can anyone please help me with that.

Comment: Backslash is your friend

Comment: Escape with a backslash ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape with a backslash; eg:

`$regex = "/\?symfony=\w{32}(\"|')/";`

The `"` is escaped with: `\"` because you define the string with `"`.

Comment: @vivekporwal04 ; I don't think there is a regexp class in the PHP core. In PHP we use a string and the preg_* functions.  Thanks for erasing your comment :)

Comment: thanks for the reply.I have already developed many regex which works fine with ruby, but i think now i have to modify them for using in php.

Comment: @vivekporwal04; I also work with Ruby (way less experience with Ruby than PHP), but I understand the ease of its methodology. I also believe you will need to translate them towards php..

Answer (score 2):

inside `' '` use `\'`

```
'/\?symfony=\w{32}("|\')/'
```

inside `" "` use `\"`

```
"/\?symfony=\w{32}(\"|')/"
```